# asm in C "too many memory references for `mov'"

Tags: c, assembly

I've seen the post about the same error but i'm still get error :

```
 too many memory references for `mov'
 junk `hCPUIDmov buffer' after expression
```

... here's the code (mingw compiler / C::B) :

```
    #include iostream

    using namespace std;

    union aregister
    {
        int theint;
        unsigned bits[32];
    };

    union tonibbles
    {
        int integer;
        short parts[2];
    };

    void GetSerial()
    {
        int part1,part2,part3;
        aregister issupported;
        int buffer;

        __asm(
            "mov %eax, 01h"
            "CPUID"
            "mov buffer, edx"
        );//do the cpuid, move the edx (feature set register) to "buffer"


        issupported.theint = buffer;
        if(issupported.bits[18])//it is supported
        {
            __asm(
                "mov part1, eax"
                "mov %eax, 03h"
                "CPUID"
            );//move the first part into "part1" and call cpuid with the next subfunction to get
            //the next 64 bits

            __asm(
                "mov part2, edx"
                "mov part3, ecx"
            );//now we have all the 96 bits of the serial number


            tonibbles serial[3];//to split it up into two nibbles

            serial[0].integer = part1;//first part
            serial[1].integer = part2;//second
            serial[2].integer = part3;//third
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `%` for all your register accesses?

Comment: I think you forgot some % signs before register names.

Comment: What are those 3 lines in the end of the question telling me that my post is mostly code?

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: You have to choose between Intel and AT&T asm syntax.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SeedmanJ Afaik, gcc only accepts AT&T syntax.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson "mov buffer, edx" is Intel syntax, so he has to change it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson gcc accepts also Intel syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397677/gcc-intel-syntax-inline-assembly

Comment: SeedmanJ/nrz, I stand corrected :)

Comment: Can we get harddrive info with asm-cpuid ?...

Answer (score 17):

Your assembly code is [not correctly formatted](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#toc3) for gcc.

Firstly, gcc uses AT&T syntax (EDIT: [by default, thanks nrz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397677/gcc-intel-syntax-inline-assembly)), so it needs a `%` added for each register reference and a `$` for immediate operands. The destination operand is always on the *right* side.

Secondly, you'll need to pass a line separator (for example `\n\t`) for a new line. Since gcc passes your string straight to the assembler, it requires a particular syntax.

You should usually try hard to minimize your assembler since it may cause problems for the optimizer. Simplest way to minimize the assembler required would probably be to break the cpuid instruction out into a function, and reuse that.

```
void cpuid(int32_t *peax, int32_t *pebx, int32_t *pecx, int32_t *pedx)
{
    __asm(
         "CPUID"
          /* All outputs (eax, ebx, ecx, edx) */
        : "=a"(*peax), "=b"(*pebx), "=c"(*pecx), "=d"(*pedx)   
          /* All inputs (eax) */
        : "a"(*peax)                                           
    );
}
```

Then just simply call using;

```
int a=1, b, c, d;

cpuid(&a, &b, &c, &d);
```

Another possibly more elegant way is to [do it using macros](http://newbiz.github.com/cpp/2010/12/20/Playing-with-cpuid.html).

Comment: This code also lacks register constraints, so as far as I know it's completely unsafe/bogus. You must tell gcc what registers you will use/clobber and where inputs/outputs go.

Comment: @R.. Yeah, my bad, I picked a bad example from the page. Replaced it with some links to info and a more relevant example.

Answer (score 6):

1. Because of how C works,

   ```
   __asm(
       "mov %eax, 01h"
       "CPUID"
       "mov buffer, edx"
   );
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   __asm("mov %eax, 01h" "CPUID" "mov buffer, edx");
   ```

   which is equivalent to

   ```
   __asm("mov %eax, 01hCPUIDmov buffer, edx");
   ```

   which isn't what you want.
2. AT&T syntax (GAS's default) puts the destination register at the end.
3. AT&T syntax requires immediates to be prefixed with $.
4. You can't reference local variables like that; you need to pass them in as operands.

[Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#Accessing_the_id_from_other_languages) gives a working example that returns eax.

The following snippet might cover your use-cases (I'm not intricately familiar with GCC inline assembly or CPUID):

```
int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
eax = 1;
__asm( "cpuid"
     : "+a" (eax), "+b" (ebx), "+c" (ecx), "+d" (edx));
buffer = edx
```