# gcc asm too many memory references

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, memory, reference

I am trying to read the time from the CMOS using asm but i get this error:

```
/tmp/ccyx8l5L.s:1236: Error: too many memory references for 'mov'
/tmp/ccyx8l5L.s:1240: Error: too many memory references for 'out'
/tmp/ccyx8l5L.s:1244: Error: too many memory references for 'in'
/tmp/ccyx8l5L.s:1252: Error: too many memory references for 'mov'
```

and here is the code:

```
for (index = 0; index < 128; index++) {
    asm("cli");
    asm("mov al, index"); /* Move index address*/
    asm("out 0x70,al"); /* Copy address to CMOS register*/
    /* some kind of real delay here is probably best */
    asm("in al,0x71"); /* Fetch 1 byte to al*/
    asm("sti"); /* Enable interrupts*/
    asm("mov tvalue,al");

    array[index] = tvalue;
}
```

I am using gcc to compile

Comment: possible duplicate of [asm in C "too many memory references for \`mov'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035379/asm-in-c-too-many-memory-references-for-mov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Janycz points out, your code uses intel syntax for the assembler, while gcc (by default) expects at&t.  If you are using gcc, how about something like this:

```
int main()
{
   unsigned char array[128];

   for (unsigned char index = 0; index < 128; index++) {

      asm("cli\n\t"
         "out %%al,$0x70\n\t"
         /* some kind of real delay here is probably best */
         "in $0x71, %%al\n\t" /* Fetch 1 byte to al*/
         "sti" /* Enable interrupts*/

         : "=a" (array[index]) : "a" (index) );
   }

}
```

This minimizes the amount of asm you have to write (4 lines vs your 6) and allows the compiler to perform more optimizations.  See the docs for gcc's [inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) to understand how all this works.

I haven't tried running this, since it won't run on protected mode operating systems (like Windows).  `In` and `Out` are protected instructions and can't be used by user-mode applications.  I assume you are running this on DOS or something?

Answer (score 2):

gcc uses AT&T syntax.
Compile with `-masm=intel`