# Referencing memory operands in .intel_syntax GNU C inline assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, inline-assembly, intel-syntax

I'm catching a link error when compiling and linking a source file with inline assembly.

Here are the test files:

```
via:$ cat test.cxx
extern int libtest();
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return libtest();
}

$ cat lib.cxx
#include <stdint.h>
int libtest()
{
    uint32_t rnds_00_15;    
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix         ;\n\t"
        "mov DWORD PTR [rnds_00_15], 1  ;\n\t"
        "cmp DWORD PTR [rnds_00_15], 1  ;\n\t"
        "je  done                       ;\n\t"
        "done:                          ;\n\t"
        ".att_syntax noprefix           ;\n\t"
        :
        : [rnds_00_15] "m" (rnds_00_15)
        : "memory", "cc"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and linking the program results in:

```
via:$ g++ -fPIC test.cxx lib.cxx -c
via:$ g++ -fPIC lib.o test.o -o test.exe
lib.o: In function `libtest()':
lib.cxx:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `rnds_00_15'
lib.cxx:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `rnds_00_15'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The real program is more complex. The routine is out of registers so the flag `rnds_00_15` must be a memory operand. Use of `rnds_00_15` is local to the asm block. It is declared in the C code to ensure the memory is allocated on the stack and nothing more. We don't read from it or write to it as far as the C code is concerned. We list it as a memory input so GCC knows we use it and wire up the "C variable name" in the extended ASM.

Why am I receiving a link error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `uint32_t rnds_00_15;` is a local with automatic storage.  Of course it there's no asm symbol with that name.  Did you mean `%[rnds_00_15]`?  And hopefully with a `"+m"` read/write operand if you're going to store `1` into it.  Or simply `"=m"` if you want the compiler to reserve you some scratch space on the stack.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I don't believe Intel syntax uses the percent sign. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: The % is part of the "replacement pattern" in gcc - I don't use Intel syntax much, but I'm pretty sure Peter is right - or on the right track.

Comment: Probably close enough to be a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397677/how-to-set-a-variable-in-gcc-with-intel-syntax-inline-assembly
(Which uses %0 and %1 for substitutions.

Comment: OK, thanks. Using `%[rnds_00_15]` results in `Error: junk '(%ebp)' after expression`. This is why I avoid that crappy GCC inline assembly at nearly all costs. Man I despise this crappy tool.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. You shouldn't be such a coward. You should comment on the downvote. I comment on the questions I hit.

Comment: Once again - here now is the downvote and comment you requested. And you're absolutely full of crap claiming that you comment on the downvotes you give, half the time I just know it's you because I see every answer getting downvoted at the same time and then I see that you had logged in right before the downvote happened. Stop mass downvoting people and you probably won't accumulate so many downvotes in return.

Comment: Thnaks @EdMorton. Not sure what you are talking about. I'll be responding in kind.

Comment: I'm talking about you being so infamous for your behavior that people refer to mass downvoting as being jww-ed and someone (no, it wasn't me - I'd proudly claim it if it had been) even wrote a tool for people to know if they had been jww-ed (the kind where you do leave a comment which is maybe half the time). See http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/890812/have-i-been-jwwed. If you change your behavior then you won't have to worry about who's downvoting you.

Comment: That's too funny. Thanks man!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile with `gcc -masm=intel` and don't try to switch modes inside the asm template string.  AFAIK there's no equivalent before clang14 (Note: MacOS installs clang as `gcc` / `g++` by default.)

Also, of course you need to use valid GNU C inline asm, using operands to tell the compiler which C objects you want to read and write.

- [Can I use Intel syntax of x86 assembly with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc) **clang14 supports `-masm=intel`** like GCC
- [How to set gcc to use intel syntax permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953951/how-to-set-gcc-to-use-intel-syntax-permanently)  clang13 and earlier didn't.

---

> I don't believe Intel syntax uses the percent sign. Perhaps I am missing something?

**You're getting mixed up between `%operand` substitutions into the Extended-Asm template (which use a *single* `%`)**, vs. the final asm that the assembler sees.

You need `%%` to use a literal `%` in the final asm.  You wouldn't use `"mov %%eax, 1"` in Intel-syntax inline asm, but you do still use `"mov %0, 1"` or `%[named_operand]`.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  In Basic asm (no operands), there is no substitution and % isn't special in the template, so you'd write `mov $1, %eax` in Basic asm vs. `mov $1, %%eax` in Extended, if for some reason you weren't using an operand like  `mov $1, %[tmp]` or `mov $1, %0`.

---

`uint32_t rnds_00_15;` is a local with automatic storage. Of course it there's no asm symbol with that name.

**Use `%[rnds_00_15]` and compile with `-masm=intel`**  (And remove the `.att_syntax` at the end; that would break the compiler-generate asm that comes after.)

You also need to remove the `DWORD PTR`, because the operand-expansion already includes that, e.g. `DWORD PTR [rsp - 4]`, and clang errors on `DWORD PTR DWORD PTR [rsp - 4]`.  (GAS accepts it just fine, but the 2nd one takes precendence so it's pointless and potentially misleading.)

And you'll want a `"=m"` output operand if you want the compiler to reserve you some scratch space on the stack.  You must not modify input-only operands, even if it's unused in the C.  Maybe the compiler decides it can overlap something else because it's not written and not initialized (i.e. UB).  (I'm not sure if your `"memory"` clobber makes it safe, but there's no reason not to use an early-clobber output operand here.)

And you'll want to avoid label name conflicts by using `%=` to get a unique number.

**Working example (GCC and ICC, but not clang unfortunately)**, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAguatd5AM1W1rAemerkrMFIKrgmHwQIeIKqRKoA7iQA1hGECO7MbAaqqtgAbpgsqgYKBJgMAPqCAJ76TAAequiomIIsXj4I%2BQAO1rmqDHgARnk6Bbn5EACU1hwA7HyWKSkiubJcBT7ELOiCBWZmBbQArBqTFtOqrqoAkvr5qiVllajNmMSs6AC0gngAXpjurKqoLAzFqi6n1QGWIxDwWCy4TiPzuDxWqgAthg8HY8PdBNZDscgR4RIJPoFPphys1WK9fqoFEoVLVVN8Sc1OshCKoACIAdQA8gAlNmqAAKABUeVjpgUCkxBIiJaoJWlUMwCHgGJgJWKUhAUsduFwcudClcCBVVCxbsRMGjKhxtpoWDbNARdRrDuouFxkWk3bttjxlqt1psdja2aRHCkHfbbU73S7DrrkIjmt6bX6VmsNlsfaHw%2BpbVHHc6pq6I%2B6qJ9sgAZaosTDcXayfkl5vTSMOmNcOOt90Gau/OtcBtskAt0et/PtosHZsj1P%2BjNB7NuzuN7gANkRutUEHngazI2LJZAXZSI%2BOZoSqC6QOIgmS7mQVJCeCTzNZdhIqnKAA412HHj8YhIpgyLEACogEM0Ig%2BLc9wAcE9IMBaTDoACUqCCIiKYOgoSoICnzhOCBB5Pah6qCMsj7IcFoEGIWRmHsoxjGyoy2Jk%2BB2KMljtJ0PS1AQkoMHkyxMMqGTDExVHTLM%2BjzIsqi7pmwaUS6EpSjKBRygUCpKiqaoFC6EAnsu4w8J6DCqAAJPQKa%2Bopi4huoYyaEiIK2WmAZKdmYZOMxEYTtGU4ts6EyJkyVk2fWc7pnuwbbPy4wuWF7n2VmIY%2BeMTZtoFsZkfGZYVr2NYDkOY5ldlha5dOJa6kV/ZRY2I5lc1FUdsZs52TFXmOc6q5cBuW47l1i4HtV5GMWRNF0aoDEqZYmVcVY83cfoHTdL0Akgvc4JYAUsHwugRTvJgEnzRMLoyQQclLMNaVzWNxxnHkFlGia%2B2PC8x1fFkvz/PhPygjtmSxIEsJwQiyIceit4ujimB4gSoRNKojLknglLUsoWAhAypJvj4nK8vywqimRanSrK8qKqJenqmRRl5d2nYTOZEVhlFnWeQ58VOS5nopbdcU5r5WUBZVnaM6WzM8GFFnWezg7RVzaU84l7hJt6URKwuKvC5l/l2pOVXBbGoVJuEbMC8rQu8%2Bryb1uE2uxd5jj63mhs5RLY35dLYVdJbHMeTrNtq8l9ZdE73XxRlfnuwWbWS8u5YpHVtYNU2zXNq1QVZz2fZp4rjWZ%2BVYsJ970wdUHzs9bGfUDe626pTso2HBRUkpFNywzRNVjMdYUhDIw0jbFIpAsNIZij6g0iaPw/CXKI4ifHItCjwQE8D4PUQgLI34GNs2wbL%2Ba60LIZhrgfYwACxD1IV%2Bj4idAbGPG%2BkNPUij4IIBmKQ69SJPg84CwBgIgFAqAkx6TIBQCAaAIGqmICAYA34uCkDREJDElAuivy6AoJgYFpCr1ILArC%2BguR/GKK/LAiJWDAFVJQvAFpkBiVqK/Ek8NoKSCkIQgYDBX4EHBI/LhA9GA0JQHPXgjBuhf0gIPW4ypfhfykE8LkshVBPA5EwBgFknjUPEMYRsCApThHyNojkJJ%2BFME/ovCQdBB68KkCPF%2B/8p7SB/GuJ4a4r6%2BGQI%2BPeXBty4EIJ%2BFeYZNDgOaJAt0shaBDFULPXg/A14byGFvEAtgDBXwAJy0HPt%2Bb8V8xhrjXJkq%2Ba4xi33vqQR%2BYxtgGDMDU%2Bph8GkNO/E4yeb9pCf2/r/ZJpAgGgIglBAg5BKCwIifAugpBsJBIQfQQiTBmgEOEfYxx49nEdJkLYWgIN4huI8V44APjVB%2BKSc4lJpAmgoXuJQOx0hKmPy4FfAwmTHkvKya815sg2kuI/kIbpf8AGpOiQYd0mTtg7FoN%2BMYp9ik33sbIUeaz2nv1OQAvpID%2BkQCQGMyBIyYHhMgSgRIwA1zPzQcJL%2BEAsHrJwSwPBFChFEPASQggZD/iUJAjQuh6z8CMOYYo9pbDkAcKWeQA0or%2BEviWXY0RnAEkSN4tI4Yb9mjyJYIo5Rqj1GaIYFYsQNiYm31Wa/d%2BezPEJBoaoNcdS6kBPwEQYgUSbJhLgfcKJXBYnxL4LwVFm8LmYCuQg5V28uCZP3mMLg18zC0FoKGkpshtgVIfjva12wxjRKvrvTJ8xPFcFaUin5XSf4AuEZipAgzoJ4pxRMlB0yHWTPmYsoRtyHGIpNdIOQ/joSgzNV4pQlrrVmDqb685lysBBpbfcnetADANOibQdNELwUFO%2BRsotPSznovgFisBrqoGjIJRMvAPjIWoJVBSzB2DcH4MZcQzIrLyEcuoWwbl7TeXw35aw8o7C8iip4XwgR0qRFsDEfKgQir4CyNVejdV0gXi6A0GyYALARDiJ4LQLxmq1EaK0Wo3RyB9FskMYIYxuH1HmIeHqpetijVtvWaa38%2ByqRHMhTaswdqZlOtCYet1chZCerQyOweY7rnKvsVO4FZSL5X0zTU90Zhtj5vbb8r%2BxbklAqHfJ2QmTvy0EyZksYBmCkoPhXR5FnSN2AtvlwMzhbLN%2BtBBSceV8gA%3D) (which uses `-masm=intel` depending on options in the dropdown).  You can use "binary mode" (the 11010 button) to prove that it actually assembles after compiling to asm without warnings.

```
int libtest_intel()
{
    uint32_t rnds_00_15;
    // Intel syntax operand-size can only be overridden with operand modifiers
    // because the expansion includes an explicit DWORD PTR
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (  // ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"
        "mov %[rnds_00_15], 1  \n\t"
        "cmp %[rnds_00_15], 1  \n\t"
        "je  .Ldone%=                 \n\t"
        ".Ldone%=:                    \n\t"
        : [rnds_00_15] "=&m" (rnds_00_15)
        :
        : // no clobbers
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles (with `gcc -O3 -masm=intel`) to this asm.  Also works with `gcc -m32 -masm=intel` of course:

```
libtest_intel:
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 1  
    cmp DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 1  
    je  .Ldone8                 
.Ldone8:                    

    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

**I couldn't get this to work with clang: It choked on `.intel_syntax noprefix` when I left that in explicitly**.

---

### Operand-size overrides:

You have to use `%b[tmp]` to get the compiler to substitute in `BYTE PTR [rsp-4]` to only access the low byte of a dword input operand.  I'd recommend AT&T syntax if you want to do much of this.

---

---

> Using `%[rnds_00_15]` results in `Error: junk '(%ebp)' after expression.`

That's because you switched to Intel syntax without telling the compiler.  If you want it to use Intel addressing modes, **compile with `-masm=intel`** so the compiler can substitute into the template with the correct syntax.

> This is why I avoid that crappy GCC inline assembly at nearly all costs. Man I despise this crappy tool.

You're just using it wrong.  It's a bit cumbersome, but makes sense and mostly works well if you understand how it's designed.

Repeat after me: **The compiler doesn't parse the asm string *at all*, except to do text substitutions of `%operand`**.  This is why it doesn't notice your `.intel_syntax noprefex` and keeps substituting AT&T syntax.

It does work better and more easily with AT&T syntax though, e.g. for overriding the operand-size of a memory operand, or adding an offset.  (e.g. `4 + %[mem]` works in AT&T syntax).

---

### Dialect alternatives:

If you want to write inline asm that doesn't depend on `-masm=intel` or not, [use Dialect alternatives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Multiple-assembler-dialects-in-asm-templates) (which makes your code super-ugly; not recommended for anything other than wrapping one or two instructions):

**Also demonstrates operand-size overrides**

```
#include <stdint.h>
int libtest_override_operand_size()
{
    uint32_t rnds_00_15;
    // Intel syntax operand-size can only be overriden with operand modifiers
    // because the expansion includes an explicit DWORD PTR
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        "{movl $1, %[rnds_00_15] | mov %[rnds_00_15], 1}  \n\t"
        "{cmpl $1, %[rnds_00_15] | cmp %k[rnds_00_15], 1}  \n\t"
        "{cmpw $1, %[rnds_00_15] | cmp %w[rnds_00_15], 1}  \n\t"
        "{cmpb $1, %[rnds_00_15] | cmp %b[rnds_00_15], 1}  \n\t"
        "je  .Ldone%=                     \n\t"
        ".Ldone%=:                        \n\t"
        : [rnds_00_15] "=&m" (rnds_00_15)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

With Intel syntax, gcc compiles it to:

```
     mov DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 1  
     cmp DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 1  
     cmp WORD PTR [rsp-4], 1  
     cmp BYTE PTR [rsp-4], 1  
    je  .Ldone38                     
.Ldone38:                        

    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

With AT&T syntax, compiles to:

```
    movl $1, -4(%rsp)   
    cmpl $1, -4(%rsp)   
    cmpw $1, -4(%rsp)   
    cmpb $1, -4(%rsp)   
    je  .Ldone38                     
.Ldone38:                        

    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks. Two percent signs results in `lib.cxx:21: Error: bad expression`. I think I am going to delete this question, close the bug report and move onto something more useful. I wasted four hours on GCC's broken tools. That's more time then they deserve.

Comment: @jww: Did you even read the answer?  Using `%%` will emit a literal `%[rnds_00_15]` into the asm output.  I updated with working examples.  (But I wasn't able to get Intel-syntax working with clang, only GCC and ICC.  They are not broken, only clang is (if it ever intended to support intel-syntax.)

Comment: Thanks again Peter. Yes, I did read the answer and even tried to compile the code in my test example. I accepted the answer because I trust you and your answer. There's no need to waste any more time on it.

Comment: By the way, Clang has been broken for years. LLVM can't even do a simple negate. Also see [Inline assembly operands don't work with .intel_syntax](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24232).

Comment: @jww: I've found clang's optimizer often sucks with inline asm when you give it a choice like `"rm" (some_var)`.  It tends to spill the variable to memory and pick the memory option, even if it already has it in registers.  (Obviously I was using AT&T syntax so clang could compile it.)  I'd just use intrinsics, or write whole functions in asm in a separate file if I cared about clang and really hated AT&T syntax.  Otherwise just use AT&T syntax like everyone else does.  It's not that bad once you learn to make a mental context-switch and start thinking in AT&T syntax.

Comment: *"Otherwise just use AT&T syntax like everyone else does..."* - We use Intel style because the code is shared between Windows, Unix and Linux. Microsoft's assembler needs Intel style. We gave up trying to support OS X.

Comment: gcc and clang on Windows use AT&T syntax.  You have to write the code twice for GNU C vs. MSVC inline asm syntax anyway.  (Or do your macro hacks work around that?  Can't you just have your macros reverse the operands for AT&T syntax?  There are a lot of differences in GNU vs. MSVC inline asm syntax as far as getting data into / out of an asm statement.)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh, that does work for register operands. (https://godbolt.org/g/25fnxV).  (And yeah, of course you should use `neg`, not `negl`, in Intel syntax.  An unfortunate start to that bug report.)  So clang knows how to format register operands, but not memory.  The error messages show it substituting in `mov -4(%rsp), 1` with the "Intel" button clicked, which passes `-masm=intel`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. As Peter observed in a comment, we have macros which allow us to use the same ASM source for both Windows (MASM) and Linux (GAS). There is about 4000 lines of macro'd ASM source and I don't think it is feasible to rewrite it for Clang. It would be better for everyone if Clang fixed its integrated assembler. Fixing the assembler in one place is better/more economical then hundreds of developers modifying their source code to workaround bugs.

Comment: So, is there any chance on most recent Clang to write in intel-syntax inline assembly? I managed successfully to write any intel asm but when using only `r` (register) type of inputs and outputs, with `m` (memory) inputs/outputs I never succeeded on Clang, although tried different ways. Also `-masm=intel` seems to be just ignored by Clang.

Comment: @Arty: Not that I know of, unfortunately.  I don't know how to convince clang to format operands into Intel-syntax style, or even to default to `.intel_syntax` mode when parsing the asm template.