# Bad Instruction - Inline Assembly Language in C Code

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, att

I'm trying to *exit* a program with assembly instructions, but when I compile with *gcc* it says that `mov` is a bad instruction, even when I use `movl` which I don't even know what it is. Is it even possible to exit a program with assembly instructions?

```c
int main(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %rax, $60\n\t"
        "movl %rdi, $0\n\t"
        "syscall\n");
}
// cc main.c -o main && ./main
```

Comment: Note that having `mov` instructions in inline assembly is generally a code smell.  Instead, use constraints and extended inline assembly: `asm volatile ("syscall" :: "a"(60), "D"(0));`

Comment: I encourage readers to never make system calls by crafting their own assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `movq` for 64 bit. Also, your operations are not in the correct order.

The following compiles:

```
int main(void)
{
    __asm__("movq $60, %rax\n\t"
        "movq $0, %rdi\n\t"
        "syscall\n");
}
```

Note that for any other system call (which doesn't terminate the whole program), it's necessary to tell the compiler which registers are clobbered, and usually to use a `"memory"` clobber to make sure memory is in sync with C values before a system call reads or writes memory.

Also, to pass operands, you'll need Extended asm syntax.  See [How to invoke a system call via sysenter in inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-sysenter-in-inline-assembly) for an example `my_write` wrapper.  (Which has only `"syscall"` inside the asm template; we ask the compiler to put the call number and args in the right registers instead of writing `mov`)

Comment: *operations are not in the correct order*, but when I write an (*Hello, World*) program I first use the register and then the argument. Can you explain what's the difference between Inline *asm* code in *C* and a regular *asm* program?

Comment: or you can leave off the suffixe like `q` and `l` altogether in this case since one of the operands has a known size (the register). You might also consider moving to the 32-bit registers (eax and edi) since the processor will automatically zero extend through the upper 32-bits of the corresponding 64-bit register.

Comment: @perrorundefinedvariableun: GCC's asm blocks use GAS syntax.

Comment: @perrorundefinedvariableun : they mean that in at&t syntax the source is first and the destination is second. Intel syntax is the other way around (dest, src).

Comment: @perrorundefinedvariableun and it is because when you use inline assembler in a C file, the compiler will compile it to assembler and then somewhat literally paste these among the other assembler opcodes, so even though GAS could support intel ordering, GCC wouldn't.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: `gcc -masm=intel` *does* use `.intel_syntax noprefix` at the top of the `.s` temporary it feeds to `as`.   [Referencing memory operands in .intel\_syntax GNU C inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51905409)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Doesn't that risk breaking system header files under `arch/`, or did they finally get all the `asm` blocks out of the public header files?

Comment: @Joshua: hopefully everything uses [dialect alternatives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) like `asm ("lock or{b $0, (%esp) |  byte ptr [esp], 0}" ::: "memory")` so they work with either `-masm=att` or `intel`.  But unfortunately I grepped /usr/include and the rare headers using `__asm__` at all seem to neglect this, like `sys/io.h`.  (`asm/swab.h` looks worse the GCC builtins, but actually works without needing alternatives.)  `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/include/cpuid.h` *does* use dialect alternatives, e.g. `"pushf{l|d}\n\t"`

Comment: @Joshua: `bits/fenv.h` might be the only "significant" headers that has some AT&T-only `__asm__`, but only in `__feraiseexcept_invalid_divbyzero`.  The non-SSE x87 version will maybe syntax error or maybe reverse the operands, the SSE version will do `0.0 / 1.0` instead of `1. / 0.` with `-masm=intel`.  So that sucks.