# x86-64 assembly order of operands

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, intel-syntax

What is the order of operands in x86-64 assembly?:
    instruction destination, source
Or:
    instruction source, destination

I have three books and two different approaches!

Comment: Actually, it can vary depending on what assembler you use.  There are two common standards *Intel* and *AT&T*.  There are frequent debates over which one is "better."

Comment: For *AT&T* for instance it is `cmd  source, dest` while with *Intel* it is `cmd dest, source` so it is assembler dependent.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I think the main debate is usually whether AT&T syntax is usable / bearable *at all*.  I've seen very few claims that it's better.  The most that people usually claim is that it's not worse and you can get used to it, at least compared to a nice consistent assembler like NASM.  It's pretty hard to defend a syntax that literally has design bugs (with `fsubr` vs. `fsub` being reversed for some register-register operands. 
 https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html).  Other than for x87, I don't have a problem with it after getting my brain into AT&T mode.

Comment: there's another major syntax for x86: Plan9 syntax uses in golang

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the syntax of an assembler. Mostly we have two choices: [intel-syntax](/questions/tagged/intel-syntax) and AT&T [att](/questions/tagged/att) syntaxes.  See their respective tag wikis, [intel-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info) and [att](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info).

There are multiple flavours of Intel syntax, the major ones being NASM (`mov dword [symbol_name], 1`) and MASM (including GAS's `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode which many GNU and Unix tools can use.)  See the [Intel syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info) for details on the differences and telling them apart.

Intel syntax example (from `objdump -drwC -Mintel` disassembly, so this is GNU `.intel_syntax`, with a couple examples added in):

```
push   rbp         # comment character can be # (GAS) or ; MASM/NASM
mov    rbp,rsp
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],esi
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
add    eax,edx
pop    rbp
ret

add    dword ptr [rdi], 1    # size specifier mandatory if neither operand is a reg
imul   ecx, [rdi + rax*4 + 20], 12345
```

There's only one flavour of AT&T syntax (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info):

```
push   %rbp                 # comment character is always #
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
add    %edx,%eax
pop    %rbp
retq

addl  $1, (%rdi)      # size suffix b/w/l/q used to indicate operand-size if neither operand is a register

# with more than 2 operands, reverse the whole list
imul   $12345, 20(%rdi, %rax, 4), %ecx
```

AT&T syntax is native to Unix systems. Usually, decompilers have flags to control a type of output syntax. For example `objdump` has `-Mintel` flag, gdb has `set disassembly-flavor intel` option.  GCC has `-masm=intel` which affects how inline `asm("" :::)` statements are assembled, as well as the asm the compiler feeds to the assembler.

Also, take a look at this useful site on which you can quickly see assembler output without noise [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)

---

Beware that AT&T syntax has a design bug for x87 non-commutative FP instructions like `fsub` and `fsubr` with register operands: see the manual: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html

Related:

- [What was the original reason for the design of AT&T assembly syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244028/what-was-the-original-reason-for-the-design-of-att-assembly-syntax)
- [Questions about AT&T x86 Syntax design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193827/questions-about-att-x86-syntax-design)

Comment: Compilers have options too, if you're getting asm output instead of machine code ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).  gcc/clang/icc `-masm=intel`.

Comment: Also, unix assemblers such as GNU assembler can switch syntax on the fly, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347909/673852) about "how" and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5397677/673852) with actual usage.